# How to let slf4j log exceptions in file without catching them explicitly

Tags: java, log4j, slf4j

When using slf4j you must output log explicitly, e.g., *logger.error(msg)* or *logger.info(msg)*.

When there is an exception thrown, we can let slf4j output the exception and the stacktrace into the log file by catching the exception:

```
String s = getMyString();
try {
   bool result = s.contains("ok")
} catch (java.lang.NullPointerException t) {
   log.error("null pointer detected !", t);
}
```

However, I do not want to explicitly catch every *NullPointerException* exception and want them (and stacktrace) to be output into the log file. How can we make it ?

Comment: Catching a NPE is not a good practice. Your service entry point (e.g. facade, rest endpoint) will log it for you if you catch a generic exception, won't it?